# How to set the direction or language of a react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem that in my emulator that installed on my computer the components direction is from left to right (English): [image]

But in my physical phone i see that the direction is from right to left (my phone is in Hebrew): [image]

So my question is how can i set that the app direction or language will always be in english?

Here is my code to this login component:

```
<View style={[styles.inputWrapper, {'marginBottom': 20}, this.state.usernameErr ? {'borderColor' : 'red'} : null]}>
        <View style={styles.inputLogo}><Icon name="ios-person" size={20} color="rgba(14, 54, 124, 0.83)" /></View>
        <View style={styles.inputCon}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => this.validateUsername(text)} value={this.state.username} placeholder="Username" underlineColorAndroid="transparent"/>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.inputWrapper, this.state.passwordErr ? {'borderColor' : 'red'} : null]}>
        <View style={styles.inputLogo}><Icon name="ios-unlock" size={20} color="rgba(14, 54, 124, 0.83)" /></View>
        <View style={styles.inputCon}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} secureTextEntry onChangeText={(text) => this.validatePass(text)} value={this.state.password} placeholder="Password" underlineColorAndroid="transparent"/>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Stylesheet:

```
inputWrapper: {
   flexDirection: 'row',
   borderBottomWidth: 1,
   borderColor: 'lightgrey',
   marginRight: 15,
   marginLeft: 15,
},
inputLogo: {
  paddingTop: 13,
},
input: {
  paddingBottom: 2,
  paddingLeft: 8,
  textAlign: 'left'
},
inputCon: {
  //padding: 5,
  flex: 1,
  alignSelf: 'flex-start'
},
```

Comment: Can you provice the code? Also see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FelipeAugusto edited my qeustion